# how to untar a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: tar

Whenever I am writing this:

```
tar - xvf grads-2.0.2.oga.2-bundle.tar.gz
```

I am getting this:

```
You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options
```

How to use this?

Answer (score 37):

Drop the space after `-`, or even drop `-` entirely:

```
tar xvf grads-2.0.2.oga.2-bundle.tar.gz
```

For those wondering what the options do, from `man tar`:

```
-x, --extract, --get
extract files from an archive

-v, --verbose
verbosely list files processed

-f, --file ARCHIVE
use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now". Actually I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: Is that all the output you're getting? What does `ls -l grads-2.0.2.oga.2-bundle.tar.gz` produce? It should indicate the file is 16,269,897 bytes in length.